# Take Photos iPhone stretched

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I have taken photos for iPhone 5 portrait and landscape mode. photos reduced size  320 * 242
both modes but portrait mode photos stretched and landscape working perfectly

image view content mode set aspectfill.
instagram application take photos landscape and portrait mode.not stretched any photos that size maintain  320 * 427

my didfinishwithmedia info code below:

```
 else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(__bridge NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
{
    _imgcount = 0;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    CGFloat imgHeight = image.size.height;
    CGFloat imgWidth = image.size.width;
    CGFloat resizeWidth = 320;
    CGFloat resizeHeight = 240;
    if (imgWidth > imgHeight) {
        resizeHeight = imgHeight * 320/imgWidth;
    }
    else if (imgWidth < imgHeight || imgHeight == imgWidth){
        resizeWidth = imgWidth * 240/imgHeight;
    }
     UIImage *compressedImage = [self scaleImage:image toSize:CGSizeMake(resizeWidth, resizeHeight)];
    if (checkgallery) {
        _imgcount += 1;
        imgBannerimage.image = compressedImage;
    }
    else{
        strMediatype = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image"];
        imgtblVideo.image =compressedImage;
    }
    [tblDealership reloadData]; // Update table UI
}];
 }




 -(UIImage *)scaleImage:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize
  {
//    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize,NO,0.0);
 [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
 UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return newImage;
  }
```

suggest with your ideas..

Comment: post code of didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method.

Comment: best way to check image orinetation and acoordiang to orientation you have to compress image.

Comment: ok fine check image orientation but how to get landscape image quality in portrait mode...